# Libgdx pools for different types of childs objects

Tags: java, memory-management, libgdx

I have a unit class and some subclasses of it (Archer, Swordsman, etc).
How can i make a pool that recycles all those subclasses of type unit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible, because a `Pool` can only contain one certain type of objects. Otherwise you might have something like this:

```
Pool<Unit> unitPool = ...;
Archer acher = new Archer();
unitPool.free(archer); // we free an Archer, who is a Unit
Unit swordsmanUnit = unitPool.obtain(); // we can obtain only Units
Swordsman swordsman = (Swordsman) swordsmanUnit; // This is actually an Archer and will result in a ClassCastException
```

Fortunately, libgdx comes with a utility called `Pools` for easy pooling of many different classes. It creates a `ReflectionPool` for each class and frees/obtains your objects from the correct pool. Just make your `Unit` class `Poolable`.

```
Archer archer = Pools.obtain(Archer.class);
Swordsman swordsman = Pools.obtain(Swordsman.class);
// ...
Pools.free(archer);
Pools.free(swordsman);
```